# JavaScript evaluation order when assigning

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator, operator-precedence

At what point does JavaScript determine the left-hand side of an assignment — is it before or after the right-hand side is evaluated?

For example, what does this code do?

```
var arr = [{thing:1},{thing:2},{thing:3},{last:true}];
arr[arr.length - 1].newField = arr.pop();
```

Answer (score 3):

The left-hand side of an assignment operator is evaluated first.

The specification for this as of ES2015 can be found in the ["Runtime Semantics: Evaluation" portion of the "Assignment Operators" section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and can be very roughly summarized as:

1. Evaluate the LHS to determine the reference
2. Evaluate the RHS to determine the value
3. Assign the value to the reference

With regards to the array `.pop()` example, it might have looked like it would assign the originally last item to a field in the resulting last item — but that would only happen if the RHS were evaluated first, rather than the LHS.

What actually happens is that the left-hand side first yields a reference to the original last object `{last:true}`. After this, the `array.pop()` returns the same object after removing it from the end of the array. Then the assignment happens, so that the object ends up looking like `obj =
 {last:true, newField:obj}`. Since no reference to `obj` was kept in the original example,

Expanding the assignment out to code instead, and adding a couple extra variables so we can check the behavior, might look something like this:

```
function pseudoAssignment() {
  // left-hand side evaluated first
  var lhsObj = arr[arr.length - 1];
  var lhsKey = 'newField';

  // then the right-hand side
  var rhsVal = arr.pop();

  // then the value from RHS is assigned to what the LHS references
  lhsObj[lhsKey] = rhsVal;

  // `(a = b)` has a value just like `(a + b)` would
  return rhsVal;
}

var arr = [{thing:1},{thing:2},{thing:3},{last:true}];
_lastObj = arr[arr.length - 1];

// `arr[arr.length - 1].newField = arr.pop();`
_result = pseudoAssignment();

console.assert(_lastObj.newField === _lastObj,
  "The last object now contains a field recursively referencing itself.")
console.assert(_result === _lastObj,
  "The assignment's result was the object that got popped.")
console.assert(arr.indexOf(_lastObj) === -1,
  "The popped object is no longer in the array.")
```

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to monitor what is happening during this assignment, is defining a proxy on the array:

```js
var arr = [{thing:1},{thing:2},{thing:3},{last:true}];

arr = new Proxy(arr, {
    get: function (obj, key) {
        console.log('getting ', key);
        return obj[key];
    },
    set: function (obj, key, value) {
        console.log('setting ', key, ' to ', value);
        return obj[key] = value;
    }
});

arr[arr.length - 1].newField = arr.pop();
```

Now the console will show when the array properties (including numerical indexes, `length` and `pop` method) are accessed and when they are set.

The first two lines illustrate that the left side is evaluated first:

> getting  length
>   getting  3

The other lines are generated during the execution of `pop`:

> getting  pop
>   getting  length
>   getting  3
>   setting  length  to  3